# How to set Permission for Sharepoint 2019 site on-premises project

Tags: asp.net, database, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

All department is having same landing page where everyone can access

- Now i need to set permissions on inner pages of my website
  example - There are 2 departments HR and Accounts
- now HR only should access its related pages and accounts departments users should not be able to access.

Please anyone have faced similar issues please let me know the solution

Answer (score -1):

Permission on inner pages of the main site
1 - use sp admin user
2 - click on settings then site permission
3 - set the permission